# Reverse viewshed analysis in QGIS (finding a point with the largest view of an area)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, viewshed

Planning a drone survey which will be terrain following at 10m above the surface. I am trying to plan where I will be controlling the drone from where I can have line of site to the drone. I have made some guesses and ran those points through the Visibility analysis pluggin which was helpful, but I was wondering if there was a way for it to tell me the best place, rather than me guess at where the best places are, make points there, and test and compare results.

Comment: Do you have a DSM of the area?

Comment: I do. 1m LiDAR derived DSM